# How to remove the white margin of ggord in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFlLW.png). I am using the following package and script to do a biplot. But the figure output always has white margins on the top and bottom of the actual figure. I tried removing them using `plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0, 0)`, but no luck. Any thoughts on how to do this or is it just the default and there is nothing that can be done?

The script (I am using the example, but the same issue with mine):

```
>library(devtools)
>library(ggord)
>ord <- prcomp(iris[, 1:4])
>p <- ggord(ord, iris$Species)
>p
```

The problem is the white margins on the top and bottom as [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kh8T.png). How can I remove them?

Answer (score 1):

The white space you are seeing is a function of the window size when you save the image.  If you resize your window vertically or horizontally, you'll notice that the white space shrinks or grows.

If your goal is to save the plot as a PNG image, you can export it directly to file with your desired dimensions as follows:

```
png("plot1.png", 800, 300);
    p;
dev.off();
```

Adjust the `800` to the desired length and the `300` to the desired height, in pixels.  If the size is larger than the actual graph, it will pad with blank space.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually also coord_fixed(ratio =x) worked!